# Comparing Python dictionaries --> biggest entry

Tags: python, dictionary

I have several dictionaries:

```
a["size"] = 12    
b["size"] = 10
c["size"] = 11
```

I need the variable name (a,b or c) with the biggest "size" entry --> How would you implement it? I coud do it with a few if statements. But is there an easier way? It would be easy (with max(..)) if I would need the biggest number.

Comment: Do you allow to make a dict like {'a': a, 'b':b, 'c':c} before ?

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> a = {'size': 12}
>>> b = {'size': 10}
>>> c = {'size': 11}
>>> l = locals()
>>> max("abc", key=lambda x: l[x]['size'])
'a'
```

Comment: Hooo I did not know locals(). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use code below to get dict variable name with biggest size, **without knowing names of your variables**:

```
items = locals()

biggest = 0
a = {'size': 0}
b = {'size': -1}
c = {'size': 5}
d = {'size': 10}
e = {'size': 20}
for key in items.keys():
    if type(items[key]) == dict:
        size = items[key].get('size')
        if size is not None and items[key].get('size') > biggest:
            biggest = size
            name = key
print name
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use list comprehension:

```
val=max([x["size"] for x in [a,b,c]])
```